# Install gigabyte ATI Radeon™ HD 4670 in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: drivers, 20.04, radeon, amd-graphics, gigabyte

I downloaded the Linux x86_64 file from the link below

https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/ati-radeon-hd-4000-series/ati-radeon-hd-4650

and install but get this error

https://cdn1.bbcode0.com/uploads/2020/10/26/c6fdb0e7d7fcdf5b21f66ffc4d40a862-full.png

How can I use my graphics card in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want this driver for the [ATI Radeon HD 4670](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/ati-radeon-hd-4000-series/ati-radeon-hd-4670). Hope this solves your issue.